# Google App Engine (Python) : use UserProperty with Webapp2 User Model

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

i have an application where we allow users to use Oauth2 for authentication and even Custom User Registrations. All the Users are saved into the default User entity in the datastore. If the user is logging in using Oauth2 for the first time a new record in the default User entity is created like this:

```
  """Check if user is already logged in"""
  if self.logged_in:
    logging.info('User Already Logged In. Updating User Login Information')
    u = self.current_user
    u.auth_ids.append(auth_id)
    u.populate(**self._to_user_model_attrs(data, self.USER_ATTRS[provider]))
    u.put()
  else:
    """Create a New User"""
    logging.info('Creating a New User')
    ok, user = self.auth.store.user_model.create_user(auth_id, **self._to_user_model_attrs(data, self.USER_ATTRS[provider]))

    if ok: 
      self.auth.set_session(
        self.auth.store.user_to_dict(user)
      )   
self.redirect(continue_url)
```

for custom registrations records are inserted through the following handler.

```
class RegistrationHandler(TemplateHandler, SimpleAuthHandler):

  def get(self):
    self.render('register.html')

  def post(self):
    """Process registration form."""
    user = 'appname:%s' % self.request.get('email')
    name = '%s %s' % (self.request.get('first_name'), self.request.get('last_name'))
    password = self.request.get('password')
    avatar = self.request.get('avatar')
    act_url = user_activation.Activate(self.request.get('first_name'), self.request.get('email'))
    ok, user = User.create_user(auth_id=user, name=name, password_raw=password, email=self.request.get('email'))
    if ok: 
      self.auth.set_session(self.auth.store.user_to_dict(user))
      acc = models.Account(display_name=self.request.get('first_name'), act_url=act_url, act_key=act_url.split('activate/')[1], user=users.User(User.get_by_auth_id(self.current_user.auth_ids[0]).email))
      acc.put()
      if avatar:
        avt = models.Picture(is_avatar=True, is_approved=True, image=avatar, user=users.User(User.get_by_auth_id(self.current_user.auth_ids[0]).email))
        avt.put()
    self.redirect('/')
```

Now we are using webapp2_extras.sessions for session handling. We have different models like, Comments, Images, Reviews etc in which we want to use db.UserProperty() as the author field. However, the author field shows blank or None whenever we enter a record into any of these models using 'users.get_current_user()'. I think this is because we are handling the sessions through webapp2 sessions.

What we want to achieve is to be able to use the db.UserProperty field in various models and link appropriately to the current user using webapp2 sessions ?

the UserProperty() has to be passed with a User Object in order for it to properly insert the records. Even though we are able to enter the records using the following code :

```
user = users.User(User.get_by_auth_id(self.current_user.auth_ids[0]).email)
```

or

```
user = users.User(User.get_by_auth_id(self.current_user.auth_ids[0]).name)
```

but then we are not able to get the whole user object by referencing to model.author

Any ideas how we should achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using UserProperty to store references to the webapp2 user objects, you should instead store the auth_id as a StringProperty and add a convenience method for fetching the corresponding webapp2 user entity.

Something like this

```
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User

class Comment(db.model):
  text = db.StringProperty()
  author = db.StringProperty()

  def get_author(self):
    return User.get_by_auth_id(self.author)
```

Comment: From the Google App Engine docs at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects - "Both the db and NDB libraries have UserProperty property types so that applications can store user values. However, since **these values become invalid when users change email address**, most applications have no good use for this feature."

Answer (score 4):

OAuth 2.0 is not currently supported by [Users service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/). Supported options are

- Google Accounts
- OpenId
- OAuth 1.0

I don't frankly understand what you're trying to accomplish with introducing db.User in to the codebase. Given there's `self.current_user`, I assume you're already handling authentication process.

When you do `self.auth.store.user_model.create_user` - that already gives you a webapp2's user object/entity (it has nothing to do with db.User though). I believe that's what you'll have to use as  your author field given OAuth 2.0 constraint.

`users.get_current_user()` relies on a special cookie (App Engine internal). In fact, it has nothing to do with webapp2's session (or any other "custom" session for that matter). You could hack it by setting the cookie to a value that App Engine internals can understand and be tricked as if a user were logged in with one of the methods I mentioned, but I wouldn't recommend this approach. It is not documented (cookie name, format, etc.) and might be changed at any time.